# jQuery extend makes Array.prototype.push error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, constructor, extend

Ive tried some extend script with jQuery. Here is the code atm:

http://teszt.aloetravel.com/cica/test.html

My problem is that, it's works perfectly in JS Bin but in the editor mode only! Nowhere else :(

http://jsbin.com/epiked/2 < JSBin here, error is the same. Now try to edit it, and it will work.

Why? :(

The error message I have:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.push called on null or undefined
e.fn.e.pushStackjquery.min.js:2
f.each.f.fn.(anonymous function)jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function)2:66
f.extend._Deferred.e.resolveWithjquery.min.js:2
e.extend.readyjquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.C
```

What is the problem? I did not use push method in my script. So in must be something extending error, while I'd like to use parent->child relations on jQuery and my other scripts.

Comment: What do you mean by "works perfectly"? From what I see there are the same JS errors in both jsbin version and your script. Oh one more thing - in jsbin version you in fact get the blue "Click me" div displayed, but it's probably due to the fact that execution of that code is wrapped in jsbin environment.

Comment: Yep, I know, but that means they use a better or supplemented jQuery script?

Comment: You really shouldn't try merging the jQuery into your custom objects. Use jQuery through `$(...)` and, if you want to create a custom jQuery function, add it to the `$.fn` object.

Comment: The jQuery version is the same one - it's your code that triggers the errors.

Answer (score 0):

To simply get rid of errors you're getting, return something from your constructors (propably to keep jQuery chaining happy). http://jsbin.com/epiked/3

*Note: Although your code won't throw errors no more (after my fixes), take ThiefMaster comment into an account and consider once again what you're trying to achive by extending your objects with jQuery. Maybe it's not the best way to go, unless you're absolutely sure that you know what you're doing.*